# Shaky sound from speakers?

Tags: sound, speakers, setup, troubleshooting

I am pretty new to this, just trying to get everything to work.

I have an Onkyo TX-8050 receiver hooked up to a set of Paradigm Atom V7 speakers. I am playing from a turntable Audio Technical AT-LP60 connected through phono.

When I turn up the volume, the sound it is producing is what I would describe as "shaky", or trembling (not distortion). When I turn up the volume, it is no where near "loud". It happens only when hooked up to my turntable, I have separately tested the turntable with another speaker, and the stereo with another audio source (to even louder volume), and they were both fine.

What could be the possible cause of this? I have already swapped in another turn table, but the problem is still there. I am suspecting a setup/settings issue, but have no clue what it might be. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about a recording of the shaky sound?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found the problem! My table was vibrating from the speakers, causing the turntable to vibrate and produce the "shaky" sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the problem, I will share this with anyone that may run into this in the future. It was a simple problem yet I could not notice it at first. The table I had my turntable on was vibrating from the speakers, thus causing the stylus to shake all over the record.

Comment: We had exactly the same problem with our stereo setup in the studio - a temporary low quality turntable placed too close to the speakers - and it was not only mechanically induced resonance (I solved that with foam), but also the bass waves them selves that caused the cheap plastic casing to resonate. Get a heavy turntable with good mechanical isolation/suspension